# gethostbyname() segmentation fault

Tags: c, unix, networking

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char    *ptr, **pptr;
    char    str[100];
    struct hostent *hptr;
    int     i=0;

    while(--argc>0)
    {
      ptr=*(++argv);
      if((hptr=gethostbyname(ptr))==NULL)
      {
        printf("gethostbyname() error for host: %s: %s", ptr, hstrerror(h_errno));
        exit(1);
        continue;
      }

      printf("official hostanme: %s \n", hptr->h_name);

      for(pptr=hptr->h_aliases; *pptr!=NULL; pptr++)
        printf("\talias: %s \n", *pptr);

      switch(hptr->h_addrtype)
      {
      case AF_INET:
        pptr=hptr->h_addr_list;

        for(; *pptr!=NULL; pptr++)
          printf("\taddress: %s \n", inet_ntop(hptr->h_addrtype, *pptr, str, sizeof(str)));
        break;

      default:
        printf("unknown addres type");
        break;
      }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Why does this code give me a segmentation fault?

Until the output of offical name, it's fine. But after that, it gives me a fault.

I think there is no syntactical problem in this source code. What's the problem then?

Comment: [POSIX.1-2008 removes the specifications of gethostbyname(), gethostbyaddr(), and h_errno, recommending the use of getaddrinfo(3) and getnameinfo(3) instead.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname)

Comment: You *are* checking that any of the `char*` pointers that `h_aliases` is pointing to is non-NULL. `h_aliases` itself might, however, be NULL as well (i.e. no aliases there) - And you are *not* checking that.

Comment: You want to run the code inside a debugger to find the exact line of code the program crashes then inspect all variables involved to learn what's really going on.

Comment: @tofro: If `h_aliases` is `NULL`  `gethostbyname()` is broken.

Comment: `I think there is no syntactical problem in this source code.` syntactical problem is not even a real problem.

Comment: Did you compile with `-Wall -Werror`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a 64bit platform the code loses 32bit of the pointer value returned by `inet_ntop()` as it's not prototyped. Due to the latter the compiler assumes it returned an `int` which mostly likely is only 32bit width, where as a pointer is 64 bit.

Losing 32bit renders the pointer value returned invalid, so passing it to `printf()` invokes undefined behaviour, which luckily crashed the program.

To fix this either add the missing prototype:

```
const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, socklen_t size);
```

or just include the appropriate header

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

The compiler most likely warned you about this. Take such warnings serious and fix code until no more warnings are issued.